# Entities with no unique identifier in ER-Diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd

I'm drawing an ER-Diagram for school. My problem are teachers and students. How would I uniquely identify those? Is there such a thing as a "composite key"? If there is, how do I mark it in the ER-diagram or should use a teacherID and studentID?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that "*teachers*" and "*students*" are entities in your diagram. If you want to identify those, you should use a unique key for each one. Say "*teacherID*" and "*studendID*" respectively.

A composite ***attribute*** on the other hand is something that looks like this:
[composite attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqODG.jpg).
This is used for packing attributes into one attribute. I am not sure that this is what you are looking for since "*teachers*" and "*students*" are probably different entities.